# Using newpax for table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, luatex, pdf, pax

I try to use `newpax` package to generate a linkable table of contents that include the sections from included pdfs. However, the toc links go always to the end of the document.

###### MWE:

`doc-input.tex`

```
\DocumentMetadata{uncompress}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1},
   pdfauthor=Author,pdftitle=title,pdfcreator=creator}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
% from \@starttoc, but without re-reading, creates toc file 
\newwrite\tf@toc
\immediate\openout\tf@toc\jobname.toc\relax
\makeatother

\setcounter{section}{2} % to ensure correct section numbers
\setcounter{page}{3}    % ... and page numbers

\section{Section 3}\label{sec}
See Section~\ref{sec2}\par
\kant[3-6]
\section{Section 4}\label{sec2}
\subsection{Section 4.1}\label{2-1}
\kant[8]
\section{Section 5}\label{sec3}
\kant[9]

\end{document}
```

`doc-input.tex` is lualatex'ed to get a pdf. This pdf is included in `doc-use-newpax.tex`:

```
\DocumentMetadata{uncompress}
\documentclass{scrarticle}

\usepackage{pdfpages,xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=blue}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
\input{doc-input.aux}
\makeatother
\usepackage{newpax}
\directlua
{
  require("newpax")
  newpax.writenewpax("doc-input")
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Main}
\kant[1-3]
\section{Next}
\kant[4]

\addtocontents{toc}{\string\input{doc-input.toc}}

\includepdf[pages=-]{doc-input}

\setcounter{section}{5}
\section{Last}
\kant[5-7]

\end{document}
```

As result I get a pdf with a visually correct toc. However, the toc links to the embedded pdf jump always to the end of document.
I guess, I miss an important point.
How can I get correct links?

PS: I'm aware of the `addtotoc` option for `\includepdf` but it gives the page only, not the correct anchor.

Comment: hm, no it won't work currently. newpax doesn't export the original names of the destinations but renumbers them.

Comment: Does it so in a predictable way, that a modified `\contentsline` macro could adjust the names?

Comment: I would have to check the details, but I doubt it. But it should be possible to output a list of names and their new name.  Open a feature request, I will think about it (but not this week ...).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have uploaded a new version (0.54) to ctan. It now stores the names of the destinations (if the destinations have names, which doesn't need to be the case if PDF has not been created by (La)TeX or as been changed by ghostscript!). With it the following works:

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{scrarticle}

\usepackage{pdfpages,xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=blue}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}


\makeatletter 
\input{doc-input.aux}
\makeatother

\usepackage{newpax}

\directlua
{
  require("newpax")
  newpax.writenewpax("doc-input")
}
\newpaxsetup{dests=all} %force import of all destinations

% a helper command to make the change in the toc easier ...
\NewDocumentCommand\setdestfilter{mm}%
 {\def\HyperDestNameFilter##1{#1##1#2}}  
 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Main}
\kant[1-3]
\section{Next}
\kant[4]

% the destinations of the included PDF have the prefix `doc-input.newpax@`:
\addtocontents{toc}{\setdestfilter{doc-input.newpax@}{}} 
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\input{doc-input.toc}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\setdestfilter{}{}}

\includepdf[pages=-]{doc-input}

\setcounter{section}{5}
\section{Last}
\kant[5-7]

\end{document}
```

Side remark: I plant the `uncompress` option in `\DocumentMetadata` everywhere as I need that for debugging, but normal documents shouldn't use that. It can make PDFs quite large ...