# How to carry over bookmarks from included pdf to main pdf?

Tags: overleaf, pdfpages, bookmarks

I am including multiple PDFs in a main latex document (on Overleaf). However, the bookmarks of these included PDFs do not carry over to the main PDF. I can see bookmarks in the included pdfs, but I include that they do not carry over to the main pdf.

Here is the command I am using to include the pdf. `\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={}]{Chapters/chapter1.pdf}.` Please let me know what I can do to get bookmarks for all the chapters I include as PDFs in my main PDF.

Chapter1.pdf bookmarks looks like this:

```
1. Introduction
2. Background
3. Related work
4. Methodology
  4.1 Method1
  4.2 Method2
5. Results
```

main.pdf bookmarks look like this

```
1. Introduction
  1.1 subsection 1
  1.2 subsection 2
Chapter 1
Chapter 2
Chapter 3
```

I want main.pdf bookmarks to be like this:

```
1. Introduction
   1.1 subsection 1
   1.2 subsection 2
2. Chapter 1
 2.1 Introduction
 2.2. Background
 2.3. Related work
 2.4. Methodology
   2.4.1 Method1
   2.4.2 Method2
 2.5. Results
3. Chapter 2
.
.
.
```

Comment: You should probably explain what you meain by bookmarks. Usially these are generated from the table of contents of the document. It **is** possible to add stuff to the main toc from `\includepdf` via another option (see the `pdfpages` manual) but the process is manual.

Comment: see newpax package which can at least copy the destinations not sure it can automatically generate links to them in the outline of the comined pdf

Comment: @DavidCarlisle newpax doesn't store or import the outline. But the destination names can be accessed and if you have a toc-file of the imported pdf you can read it in, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/695715/2388

Comment: @daleif yes! I am trying to form a table of contents for the included pdfs. I can manually add each chapter and subchapters using `\includepdf[pages=-, addtotoc={1, section, 2, Introduction, bookmark_label}]{{Chapters/chapter1.pdf}`. Is there an automated way?
`